# iPhone - initWithFrame not working for UIActivityIndicatorView?

Tags: iphone

I am using a tableview with custom cells and want to change the content of the tableview on a button click. I am using an activity indicator while the cells are loading data.

This is how I am creating the indicatorview

```
indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(141.0, 190.0, 37.0, 37.0)];
indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[[self tableView] addSubview:indicator];
```

But it appears as if the frame has no effect on the indicator. The indicator instead of displaying in the center of the table, appears in the navigation bar on the top left corner of the view.

I have no idea what is wrong with this and why this is happening. Can someone please help me out.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/95cbe49850.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/95cbe49850.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`initWithFrame:` is not the suggested method for creating a `UIActivityInidcator`.  Taking a look at the API, you can see that to create a `UIActivityIndicator`, you should use

```
[[UIActivityIndicator alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
```

Then add it to your view and set its position with `setCenter:` as suggested by Pablo.

Also, adding it to a location in a table view will make it scroll with the table if the user scrolls up or down.  If you put it in the table's superview instead, it will stay in place.

Comment: initWithFrame can be used to initialize any control.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's there.  But it is not the suggested method for certain controls where another initWith...: is supplied

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f)];
    [activityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(160.0f, 208.0f)];
    [activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Calling to **setCenter** should give the behavior you are expecting.

Good luck!

Comment: tried this. still getting it in the navbar. adding an image for reference